# Continuous map from a connected set into himself

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm reading a proof of the fact that
$$Aut(\mathbb{D}) = \{z \longmapsto \phi_{\omega}( \rho z) : \omega \in \mathbb{D}, |\rho|=1\}$$
where $\phi_{w}(z)=\frac{z-\omega}{\bar{\omega} z-1}$.
First of all we have to prove that $\phi_{w}(z)$ is an automorphism.

The proof says: "First, we observe that since $\mathbb{D}$ is connected, one has that $\phi_{w}
(\mathbb{D}) = \mathbb{D}$ is equivalent to the
fact that $\phi_{w}$ maps the unit circle into itself and $0$ to an element of $\mathbb{D}$."

I understand why the second condition implies that $\phi_{w}
(\mathbb{D}) \subseteq \mathbb{D}$, but why do we have the equality? Does this depends on $\mathbb{D}$ and $\phi_{w}$ or does it holds in general for continuous funtions and connected sets?

(I know that a simpler proof of this fact uses that $\phi_{w}$ is its own inverse, but I'd like to understand this topological fact).

Comment: No, I don't think there is a general topological argument using connectedness. You have to use the inverse map to show that this map is surjective.

Comment: Are you asking about the equivalence for arbitrary homeomorphisms $\phi\colon\mathbb{CP}^1\to \mathbb{CP}^1$?

Comment: An analytic non constant map is open, which means that interior points are mapped to interior points, so the boundary of the image is included in the image of the boundary; since the boundary of the image is  a subset of the unit circle and the image is bounded  it follows that the boundary  must be the unit circle hence the map is surjective regardless of being an isomorphism

Comment: Thank you very much @Conrad, it's clear now!

Comment: happy to be of help